# .htacces redirect moved from zencart to opencart

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, opencart

Looking for some help, Rewwite Rules arent my strong point.

Old Shopping Cart Was Zencart and we have migrated to open cart and kept all the product ID intact.  We would like to redirect OLD Urls to the new location.

Zen Cart URL
http://website.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=11294

Redirect to New Location / Opencart URL
http://website.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=11294

I have tired A few different attempts wi th no luck, just using the above urls, however, I would still need it to redirect based on the ID

Can anyone shed any light on this ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way of doing this, and that's to use OpenCart itself to rewrite the URL on the fly. So open up `/catalog/controller/common/seo_url.php`

Find this line

```
// Decode URL
```

Before it add the following

```
    if(!isset($this->request->get['_route_'])) {
        if(isset($this->request->get['main_page']) && isset($this->request->get['products_id'])) {
            if($this->request->get['main_page'] == 'product_info') {
                $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/product';
                $this->request->get['product_id'] = (int) $this->request->get['products_id'];

                unset($this->request->get['main_page']);
                unset($this->request->get['products_id']);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

What this essentially does is if the URL contains `product_info` as the `main_page` parameter, the `route` is set to `product/product` (product page route) and the `product_id` is set to the `products_id` (note the plural vs singular between the two)

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)products_id=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ /$1?route=product/product&product_id=%1 [L,NC,R=301]
```